# Remove old duplicate rows in BQ based on timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, sql-delete, bq

I have a BQ table with duplicate (x2 times) rows of the same ad_id.

I want to delete old rows with ts > 120 min where there is a newer one with the same ad_id (Schema contains `timestamp, ad_id, value. But there is not rowId`).

This is my try, is there a nicer way to do so?

```
DELETE FROM {table_full_name} o
       WHERE timestamp < TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 120 MINUTE) AND timestamp in ( 
                                            SELECT MIN(timestamp) 
                                            FROM  {table_full_name}  i 
                                            WHERE i.ad_id=o.ad_id 
                                            GROUP  BY ad_id)
```

Data example:

```
`ad-id` | `ts`             | `value`   |
`1`     | Sep-1-2021 12:01 | `Scanned` |
`2`     | Sep-1-2021 12:02 | `Error`   |
`1`     | Sep-1-2021 12:03 | `Removed` |
```

I want to clean it up to be:

```
`ad-id` | `ts`             | `value`   |
`2`     | Sep-1-2021 12:02 | `Error`   |
`1`     | Sep-1-2021 12:03 | `Removed` |
```

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190671/311130), but BQ doesn't support auto-increment for `row-id`.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480871/311130). But how can I modify it without the ts interval (as it's unknown).

Comment: Please elaborate the question. Attach samples of data to delete on what condition.

Comment: Hi OP. Let us know if the answer helped. If it's useful, consider upvoting it. If it answered your question, then please accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this script. Used `COUNT() with HAVING` to pull duplicate records with timestamp older than 120 minutes from current time using `TIMESTAMP_DIFF`.

```
DELETE
FROM `table_full_name` 
WHERE ad_id in (SELECT ad_id 
                    FROM `table_full_name`
                    GROUP BY ad_id
                    HAVING COUNT(ad_id) > 1) 
AND TIMESTAMP_DIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), timestamp, MINUTE) > 120
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]